# Where does nunit store recently loaded assemblies

Tags: nunit

When we open NUnit application it loads the assemblies that are loaded in it previously. Where does nunit store those recently loaded assemblies?

Comment: What version of NUnit are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent version of NUnit (2.5.0.9112) stores user settings in an xml document.

File location varies by user, like so:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\[user]\Application
>   Data\NUnit\NUnitSettings.xml

In the settings file, you'll see a tag for each recent file. For example:

```
<Setting name="RecentProjects.File1" value="C:\MyAssembly.dll" />
<Setting name="RecentProjects.File2" value="C:\MyAssembly2.dll" />
```

In the above example, the assembly identified in the setting with name "RecentProjects.File1" would be loaded by default.

---

**UPDATE:**
*Since the OP indicated they are using NUnit 2.4.8 and this question is still open, I figured I should update my answer.*

For version 2.4.8, the above answer is almost identical except the *Setting* name value would need to be altered as follows:

```
<Setting name="RecentProjects.V2.File1" value="C:\MyAssembly.dll" />
<Setting name="RecentProjects.V2.File2" value="C:\MyAssembly2.dll" />
```

Notice that the only difference is the addition of the text "V2". In this example, the assembly identified in the setting with name "RecentProjects.V2.File1" would be loaded by default.

Hope this answers your question.

You can find the source for these projects [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download).